# py2exe: exe not launching

Tags: python, py2exe

I wrote a GUI using Tkinter in python.
Program works fine when I launch it via `.py`
When I use py2exe, it creates a `.exe` file but when I try to run it, nothing happens. I also don't see any logs so it is very hard to debug this.

My `setup.py` looks as such:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "mainApp.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

I am using python 2.7 on Windows machine.

Comment: Try pyinstaller instead. Still finnicky but not as bad as py2exe IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a python script using Tkinter and can compile it using pyinstaller with the following command:

> C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --windowed --distpath "C:\test" script.py

To run the program:

> C:\test\script.exe

Comment: pyinstaller was much more stable